# Kineticjs - Drag Objects Between Divs (multiple stages) on iPad

Tags: ios, html, canvas, touch, kineticjs

I'm Trying to drag Kineticjs shapes between two divs which will eventually scroll. The reason is that there is a bug in kineticjs which messes up objects hit shapes when running on retina devices (pixelratio: 2) and using have a clipping mask.

Issue #884: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/884 if anyone is interested.

Forcing the pixelratio to 1 is one workaround but I'd like to try to keep it retina.

My idea is to use the DOM for clipping. Three divs – two for the "views" and one as a helper to pass the objects between them. I pretty much got it working in desktop safari:

http://jsbin.com/mileye/7/edit?html,css,js,output

There is a little wonkiness but the main problem is getting it to work on an iPad. It seems to lose the object once drag starts. On the desktop it manages to move the shape up to the helper stage and start dragging it but in mobile it will only move it and the drag ends.

Any help would be much appreciated. I think this will manage to perform pretty well once working.
thanks

Comment: What about using an actual html5 canvas that overlays the source and destination divs?  Then you could use that overlay to give the appearance of dragging between the 2 divs.

Comment: Hey @markE, that's my plan but I'm doing it with a third kinetic stage (which creates it's own canvas). The reason I'm using kinetic for that one too is that the shapes are drawn using kinetic and there is a function to move shapes between kinetic stages. I have the moving between parts down on desktop but passing the object between the canvases on mobile seems to stop the dragging. Any ideas?